# PlatformException when calling Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, latitude-longitude, geocoder

How can I convert location latitude and longitude to a formated address? I'm trying with geocoder plugin but the line-
`await Geocoder.local.findAddressesfromCoordinates(coordinates)` gives me an error with showing platform exception. I used this plugin more times and it worked nicely, but this time in all my projects it shows same error, please help to solve.

```
var coordinates = new Coordinates(latitude, longitude);
var addresses = 
await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
var first = addresses.first;
var myAddress = first.addressLine;
```

**
When I want to convert coordinates find this error :
**Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(failed, Failed, null)**
[show error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSI5T.png)**

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post full error message

Comment: Edited! Please check

Comment: i have the same problem

Comment: you should uninstall previous app when you add any new dependency in pubspec.yaml. if you don't do this, PlatformException is usual to be shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
await Geocoder.google(your_API_Key).findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
```

Instead of:

```
await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
```

Comment: is it normal for this code to throw "Bad State" error??

Comment: Please provide more details of your issue @omarYehiaTawfeek

Comment: Oh I solved it in the evening of that day and the problem was in my code. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Hey @omarYehiaTawfeek how did you fixed the bad state error? I have the same problem

Comment: @JuanMartinZabala Check that it's wrapped with await keyword and try `flutter clean` too

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the easy fix! But this google service charges fees after a certain amount of requests, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Hi, you can see Google Maps pricing here:
https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet @最白目